# Undefined method 'claims'

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

There is an error at method `claims()`.
What I want to do is get the uid from the verified token (I think ?). So as the result, wherever I try to login (correct email and password), it will always throw "Wrong password" error.

```
try {
            $user = $auth->getUserByEmail($request->email);

            try {
                $signInResult = $auth->signInWithEmailAndPassword($request->email, $request->password);
                $idTokenString = $signInResult->idToken();

                try {
                    $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($idTokenString);
                    $uid = $verifiedIdToken->claims()->get('sub');

                    $_SESSION['verified_user_id'] = $uid;
                    $_SESSION['idTokenString'] = $idTokenString;

                    $_SESSION['status'] = "Logged in successfully";

                    return redirect()->route('userHome');
                } catch (InvalidToken $e) {
                    echo 'The token is invalid: ' . $e->getMessage();
                } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                    echo 'The token could not be parsed: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }
                
            } catch (Exception $e) {

                $_SESSION['status'] = "Wrong password";
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }
        } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\UserNotFound $e) {
            // echo $e->getMessage();
            $_SESSION['status'] = "Invalid Email Address";
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
```

There is someone having the same issue [here](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1703) but kinda confuse how they "cast" the method and why they do so.

I try to comment the code with `claims()` and add another line of code :

```
$uid = $signInResult->firebaseUserId();
```

and now it can successfully login, but will it effect the future development if I do not use `$uid` from `$verifiedIdToken` instead of `firebaseUserid()`?

Comment: the method doesn't exist, you will have to create one by yourself

Comment: but it is [here](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/2f533837091d0b76a89a059e7ed2b2732b2f459e/src/UnencryptedToken.php) , and they are under the same package ?

Comment: check version of your package. move verifiedIdToken from try - maybe token not verified and throwing 401 exception\